# Why do I get empty list or set in redis?

Tags: laravel

I am using Redis and Laravel 7. I wanna save the datas! but I dont have datas when I query it!!

that is .env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379



public function index(){

    $itemCache = "mensajes.pagina." . request('page', 1); 

    $mensajes = Cache::tags('data')->rememberForEver($itemCache, function() {
        // 1. parametro el id 2. tiempo 3. funcion anonima 
        return Mensajes::with(['mensajesJoin','note','etiqueta'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', request('sorted', 'DESC'))
        ->paginate(10);
    });
    return view('mensaje.index', compact('mensajes'));

}
```

Comment: You mean every time you run this code it runs the callback ?

Comment: exactly @apokryfos!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't cache the paginator instance (probably because it contains things that can't be serialized).

The solution for this might involve some manual work:

```php
public function index(){

   $itemCache = "mensajes.pagina." . request('page', 1); 
   $countCache = "mensajes.pagina.count";  
   $count = Cache::tags('data')->rememberForEver($countCache, function() {   
       return Mensajes::count();
   });
    
   $data = Cache::tags('data')->rememberForEver($itemCache, function() {
        // 1. parametro el id 2. tiempo 3. funcion anonima 
          
        return Mensajes::with(['mensajesJoin','note','etiqueta'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', request('sorted', 'DESC'))
        ->skip(request('page',1) - 1)*10)   
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
    });
    $mensajes = new LengthAwarePaginator($data, $count, 10, LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage('page'));

    return view('mensaje.index', compact('mensajes'));

}
```